# Rewiring a foyer ceiling lamp

Tags: electrical, wiring, receptacle, light-fixture

We have a foyer ceiling light / chandelier that accumulates dust like a magnet.  I have a haywire idea of changing the existing ceiling box into a outlet; rewiring the lamp to a plug, and using a steel cable and hand-winch to set it up for ease of cleaning.  I can go into the attic, unplug the lamp, and lower the fixture.  When done cleaning / replacing bulbs, I would just reverse the process.

Here is a loose idea of what I want to do
[image]

Question - How bad of an idea is this? I have never been able to read electrical codes and make sense of what rules I would be breaking.

Comment: I grew up in houses in India where all chandeliers were on a chain and pulley system to replace bulbs.  They were just external and visible.  You can make it a feature.  I know nothing about the code in your part of the world.

Comment: How high is the ceiling in the foyer? A plugged in load in an unattended receptacle in an attic sounds like a bad idea. A feather duster on a long pole or an extentiion tube on a vacuum sounds like a much better idea.

Comment: Foyer ceiling is about 25 feet up.  But the idea of an unattended receptacle being a problem sounds off.  I mention because every house I have been in has all sorts of outlets that are never seen but used. Appliances and things in basements / attics all the time. Is this really a concern?

Answer (score 0):

Not against code, in general. One important thing to consider:

- GFCI and/or AFCI

Depending on your location (different locations use different versions of the NEC (US) or other electrical code), you likely will need to have this protected by GFCI and/or AFCI. The rules vary a bit, but the key is that (a) existing wiring from before GFCI and/or AFCI requirements is exempt and (b) hardwired fixtures often have fewer requirements than plug/receptacle connections. Since you are *adding* a receptacle where there was none before, the current code rules will apply. So that may mean adding AFCI (which is generally done at the breaker) and/or GFCI (breaker or receptacle).

And this makes me thing of various swinging from chandeliers, etc. scenes in movies, [such as the Phantom of the Opera](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WJS7BbMpWnM). Just saying...